# Ruby class inheritance returning undefined method

Tags: ruby

I am coding a Mastermind game in Ruby and looking to add further functionality to the game whereby the player can choose between being a 'codemaker' or 'codebreaker'. To do this I have created two classes called Codebreaker & Codemaker that inherit from the Players class.

For reasons unknown when I create an instance of Codebreaker, then call the random_code method which it should have inherited from the Players Class I am getting 'undefined method shuffle' error message. Yet this method has not had a problem before with the more simplistic version.

```
class Players
   attr_accessor :peg_colors, :select_role, :select_player
   def initialize
    @peg_colors = :peg_colors
    @select_role = :select_role
    @select_player = :select_player
   end

   def random_code
    mix_colors = @peg_colors.shuffle
    mix_colors[0...4]
   end

   def player
    puts "Would you like to be the Codebreaker or Codemaker? Type your answser:"
    @select_role= gets.chomp
    @select_role = @select_role.downcase
   end
    
   def select_player(choice)    
    if choice == "codebreaker"
      @select_player = Codebreaker
    else
      @select_player = Codemaker
    end
   end

   def pegs
    @peg_colors = ['Blue', 'Pink', 'Yellow', 'White', 'Purple', 'Green']
   end

end

class Codemaker < Players
  def random_code
    get_code
  end

  def get_code    ## thids needs re-coding
    puts "\n"
    puts "#{@peg_colors}" 
    puts "\n"
    code = []
    while  code.length < 5
    code.push(gets.chomp)
    end
  end
end

class Codebreaker < Players
  def initialize
    super
  end
end
```

```
require_relative 'board.rb'
require_relative 'players.rb'
require_relative 'game.rb'

play = Players.new
pegs = play.pegs

codebreaker_or_codemaker = play.player
select_player = play.select_player(codebreaker_or_codemaker)

player = select_player.new
code = player.random_code


board = Board.new(code, pegs)
game = Game.new(board)
game.play
```

https://repl.it/@chrisrobbo/mastermind-game

Comment: Changed that to include my inline code. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: `@peg_colors` is defined in your constructor as a symbol `:peg_colors`, then you invoke `shuffle` on it, can you explain what you're trying to do there? Because that might work, but if it's an array, as it's defined in the `pegs` method, when do you invoke that method?

Comment: By using `shuffle` I am creating a random code which the player must crack. I've found the error though I am not calling the `pegs` function prior to invoking the `random_code` method.

Comment: Apologises my code is probably littered with code that is not best practice. Still early days learning :)

Answer (score 0):

The "shuffle" is method in Array class which should be available for all Array instances. I see it is working fine on the repl.com link you have shared.
If you are still facing this issue, please share the error message or verify the object by which shuffle method is called. I hope this helps. Thank you.